# cookie-based virtual service routing does not work

Tags: cookies, istio, istio-gateway

We followed the instructions in the [Istio Rules Configuration docs](https://istio-releases.github.io/v0.1/docs/concepts/traffic-management/rules-configuration.html) to setup routing rule based on a cookie.

There is the actual istio virtual service configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: prodstagingistio
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: istio-system
  creationTimestamp: "2022-07-14T16:12:56Z"
  generation: 22
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: api-gateway-virtualservice
  namespace: istio-system
  resourceVersion: "149056406"
  uid: a5be0a58-6fd8-467c-9a98-5de9ac71b1dd
spec:
  gateways:
  - api-gateway
  hosts:
  - api0-prod.dev.domain.com
  - api0-staging.dev.domain.com
  http:
  - match:
    - authority:
        exact: api0-prod.dev.domain.com
      headers:
        cookie:
          regex: ^(.*;.)?(feature-b=true)(;.*)?$
    route:
    - destination:
        host: api-gateway.blue.svc.cluster.local
  - match:
    - authority:
        exact: api0-prod.dev.domain.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: api-gateway.green.svc.cluster.local
  - match:
    - authority:
        exact: api0-staging.dev.domain.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: api-gateway.orange.svc.cluster.local
```

Supposedly, when accessing https://api0-prod.dev.domain.com with cookie value (feature-b=true) in http header, the traffic should be redirected to api-gateway.blue.svc.cluster.local. But regardless of the cookie setting, the traffic was sent to api-gateway.green.svc.cluster.local.

But I can't find anything wrong according to the document.

Can anything help taking a look of the config and see why the cookie setting doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The virtual service routes should be like below to match cookie.  Similarly you need to add for green.

```
http:
- match:
  - headers:
      cookie:
        regex: ^(.*;.)?(feature-b=true)(;.*)?$
  route:
  - destination:
      host: api-gateway.blue.svc.cluster.local 
      subset: blue-sub
```